# Java Classloader complexity

Tags: java, classloader

In trying to learn about Java class loaders from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell), I think I can see why they have the three major class loaders:

1) Bootstrap class loader
2) Extensions class loader
3) System class loader

They go on to say you can define your own classloader. I'm not sure I see the value in defining your own, but the following quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell) really makes me wonder:

> The most complex JAR hell problems arise in circumstances that take
>   advantage of the full complexity of the classloading system. A Java
>   program is not required to use only a single "flat" classloader, but
>   instead may be composed of several (potentially very many) nested,
>   cooperating classloaders. Classes loaded by different classloaders may
>   interact in complex ways not fully comprehended by a developer,
>   leading to errors or bugs that are difficult to analyze, explain, and
>   resolve.

If it's so complex, why bother with it? Shouldn't the three already-defined classloaders be enough?

(And yes, for those curious, I did run into a `ClassCastException` that I didn't think should have happened, much like the graphic labelled [Figure 2. Class identity crisis](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0429/). I'm trying to understand the background is all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain use cases require custom classloaders.
A few examples:

- Dynamically adding new folders/jars to be loadable. (Without restarting the whole application).
- Dynamically removing folder/jars from being loadable.
- Runtime bytecode generation with javassist.
- Multiple (actually used at the same time) versions of the same classes in the same application/jvm